# load tag content from another url page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a content slideshow to give a preview of a list of products.

Here is the working slideshow I had no problem to create:

```
<body>
   <script src="http://mysite.com/slideshow.php type="text/javascript">
      ...slideshow scripts here...
   </script>

   <div id="preview">
      <a href="http://mysite.com/product1/productDetail">
         <img class="imageElement" src="http://mysite.com/product1.jpg">
      </a>

      <a href="http://mysite.com/product2/productDetail">
         <img class="imageElement" src="http://mysite.com/product2.jpg">
      </a>

      ...more <a> </a>
   </div> 
</body>
```

Site visitors can click the images to open up the product detail pages.

While the images are looping through, I would like to automatically display each image's "product ID" as well. The ID's are in the product detail pages (in the above  tags) which I don't know how to retrieve & display correctly.

I tried the following but not functioning:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  $("#content").load("http://mysite.com/product1/productDetail #productID",function(){
     var sample = $('productID).text();
     $('#content').text(sample);
     });
  });
</script>
```

What did I do wrong?

***Update:***

I realized that the load was pointing at a static url so I changed the code to:

```
<script>
   $("#preview a").each(function(index){
      var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
      $("#content").load(url+" #productID",function(){
        var sample = $("#productID").text();
        $("#content").text(sample);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Still not working!!!

Comment: You have a typo error, $('productID) is missing one ' at the end: $('productID')

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected it but still not working.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not loading the product ID in the same code that loops through the images?

Comment: The slideshow was inserted to my site from an external server. I figured it was probably easier just have a div tag showing next to it to display the product ID.

Comment: I am not very clear about load() syntax, does the url address has to end with .php or .html? I am using wordpress Thesis theme, the url address takes page title slug as part of the url.

Comment: The URL doesn't matter, so long as the server recognises it as valid. However, you need to synchronise your display of the product ID with whichever image is currently being displayed (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

`$(..).load()` will load data and then place it into the matched element (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). Your current code will try and replace the `#content` div with the *entire* page, rather than just the product ID. You are better off using `$.get` or `$.ajax` for this.

In addition, your current code will just cycle through each link and update the `#content` div with the product ID, but it will just cycle as fast as possible rather than synchronising with your slide-show. You need to detect which image/link is currently being displayed and then load the product ID for that particular image.

Comment: I think your concern about the sync issue makes sense to me. I will have to look into it. Thanks so much for pointing it out.